# Making an animated background for an android app not working

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable android.widget.RelativeLayout.getBackground()' on a null object reference

I am creating an android app and want to have an animated background for it.
Unfortunatelly, I get this error here and I have no idea why it is so.

Here is the XML that I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/myLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/my_bg_animate"
    tools:context=".AccessControlActivity">

    <LinearLayout
         ..../>

    <TextView
        .... />


    <ImageView
         .... />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the java file/class:

```
    public class AccessControlActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        ConstraintLayout myLayout;


        NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;
        Button btnPositive, btnNegative;
        Dialog epicDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            RelativeLayout relativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
            AnimationDrawable animationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) relativeLayout.getBackground();
            animationDrawable.setEnterFadeDuration(4500);
            animationDrawable.setExitFadeDuration(4500);
            animationDrawable.start();




            }
}
```

And that are the errors I see when I attempt to run the programm:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nfc.netvision/com.nfc.netvision.AccessControlActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable android.widget.RelativeLayout.getBackground()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable android.widget.RelativeLayout.getBackground()' on a null object reference
        at com.nfc.netvision.AccessControlActivity.onCreate(AccessControlActivity.java:37)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Thank you in advance! Looking forward to some answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
```

After onCreate you didn't `setContentView` and directly executed `findViewById` because of that your `RelativeLayout` is null and running method of it causes exception.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. I wrote this  - `setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);` but I got an error - Cannot resolve symbol 'myLayout'

Comment: does res/layout/myLayout.xml exists in your project? make sure you don't have a typo and file exists, if yes try rebuilding the project

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined the layout where you want to inflate the view on the onCreate method, write the next line after super.. :

```
setcontentview(R.layout.yourLayoutname);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Which variable should be in the place of yourLayoutname? I gave an id in the xml android:id="@+id/myLayout" but when I write myLayout instead of yourLayoutname, I get this error - Cannot resolve symbol 'myLayout'

Comment: The name of the xml file